# RPi Case that covers SDCARD port

Tags: case

I need to send some RPi units to our remote offices, along with some specialized USB hardware, to perform pre-defined plug-and-play functions which we have developed. We don't want the SDCARD to be visible from outside the case, to reduce confusion and prevent users from doing stupid things like removing it and reinstalling backward or losing it.

Is anyone aware of a case for RPI 3/3B/4 that covers the SDCARD so it's not visible unless the case is disassembled?

As an added feature, it would be nice to have a case that lets you selectively "knock out" only the ports you want to be accessible to the end user, leaving the others covered. In my example above, we only need the power, ethernet, and one USB port. It would be nice to have all the others, including the digital IO pins, covered to prevent confusion, accidental shorting of pins, plugging into wrong hole, dust and dirt, etc.

If I can't find a better solution, I may just cover the SDCARD and unused ports with black tape before installing the RPi inside a standard case.

If anyone is aware of these types of cases, a link would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the term "Closed case" is what I need to be searching for.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 2):

One other case type you could consider is DIN rail mounting - very expensive but very rugged and configurable.

Also - 3D printing if you have access to a makerspace or school locally